# MySQL's Audit Plugin does not log the value of variables used as query arguments

Tags: mysql

I have to log the arguments of stored procedure calls where the arguments are passed as SQL variables. Unfortunately, I cannot use general logs for this purpose, because I have to enable binary logs for my other purposes and the binary & general logs cannot be enabled simultaneously.

As a solution, I am using the audit plugin framework to log the variable-typed arguments to procedure calls:

[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/8.0/en/writing-audit-plugins.html](https://stackoverflow.com)

Using the audit plugin, I tested with MariaDB using the example query below:

`SET @myVar = 1 + 2; INSERT INTO TableA (column1) VALUES (myVar);`

When MariaDB is used, the audit plugin successfully logs the 'myVar' variable's dynamically concretized value (i.e., 3) being used as an argument to the INSERT query.

However, when I test this with MySQL, it only logs the variable's name 'myVar', not logging the concretized value of myVar used as the argument to the INSERT query.

I wonder if there is any way to configure the audit plugin to log the dynamically concretized variable value when used as an argument to query statements. If this is not possible, is there any other plugin that can record this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I tried to use audit plugins, but it does not work as expected.